# Combine Data of 2 Tables into 1 DataTable in Memory in WinForms

Tags: sql, winforms, datatable

I have 2 tables in the DataBase 
1. Table1 contains list Permanent Banks
2. Table2 contains list of Temporary Banks

I want to join all the Banks from both the Tables into a `DataTable` AllBanks in memory...
I Just want the SQL Statement to fill those banks in the AllBanks Table in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_%28SQL%29):

```
select *
from PermanentBanks
union 
select *
from TemporaryBanks
```

Comment: note if the tables have different structures or field orders you will need to list the fields explicitly in place of the *

Answer (score 1):

The SQL operatore to use is [UNION](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp), but you don't specify the other fields, so I assume that you want only the field that contains the bank name

```
SELECT PermanentName AS Bank from Table1
UNION
SELECT TemporaryName AS Bank from Table2
```

you could also add a predefined value to differentiate between the two input table

```
SELECT PermanentName AS Bank, 'P' as BankType from Table1
UNION
SELECT TemporaryName AS Bank, 'T' as BankType from Table2
```

It is important to remember that each SELECT statement within the UNION must have the same number of columns, expressed in the same order and with the same datatype

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using a union statement

something like:

```
select bank_id, bank_name, 'perm' bank_type
from perm_banks
union all 
select bank_id, bank_name, 'temp' bank_type
from temp_banks
```

you can make this into a view also so it works much like a table

something like:

```
create view allbanks as 
select bank_id, bank_name, 'perm' bank_type
from perm_banks
union all 
select bank_id, bank_name, 'temp' bank_type
from temp_banks
```